# How to change play_hosts from playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a file with two playbooks. Inventory is generated dynamically and there is no possibility to change it before starting playbook.

Run with command:

```
ansible-playbook -b adapter.yml --limit=host_group
```

adapter.yml

```
- name: Prepare stage
  hosts: all
  # The problem is that the inventory contains hosts in the format "x.x.x.x" ie physical address.
  # I need to run a third-party role.
  # But, it needs hosts in the format "instance-alias", that is, the name of the instance.

  tasks:
  # for this I create a new host group
  - name: Add host in new format
    add_host:
      name: "{{ item.alias }}"
      host: "{{ item.ansible_host }}"
      groups: new_format_hosts
    with_items: "{{ groups.all }}"

 # I create a new play host group that matches the previous one in a new format
  - name: Compose new play_hosts group
    add_host:
      name: "{{ item.alias }}"
      groups: new_play_hosts
    when: item.ansible_host in play_hosts
    with_items: "{{ groups.all }}"

- name: Management stage
  hosts: new_format_hosts
  # in this playbook I want to change the composition
  # of the target hosts and launch an external role
  vars:
    hostvars: "{{ hostvars }}"
    play_hosts: "{{ groups.new_play_hosts }}" # THIS DONT WORK

  - name: Run external role
    import_role:
      name: role_name
      tasks_from: file_name
```

But I can’t change play_hosts so that the launched role uses only new hosts.

How to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use: `hosts: new_play_hosts`?

Comment: I need to pass all formatted hosts to imported role.

Comment: You are calling the role for each host already.  What's the problem?  Why reset `play_hosts`?

Comment: If I specify limit in the CLI, play_hosts contains old hosts, not formatted. And the "Management" playbook does not work,  because in the "formatted" group there are are no old format hosts.

Comment: ALL the hosts are in `new_format_hosts` in the correct format, right?

Comment: Yes, but play_hosts contain hosts in the old format.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
- name: Prepare stage
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Show hostavers
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_host'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups.all }}"

  # for this I create a new host group
  - name: Add host in new format
    add_host:
      name: "{{ hostvars[item].alias }}"
      ansible_host: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}"
      groups: new_format_hosts
    with_items: "{{ groups.all }}"

- name: Management stage
  hosts: new_format_hosts
  tasks:
  - name: Ping New Format Hosts
    ping:

  - name: Show ansible_host for each host
    debug:
      var: ansible_host

  - name: Show playhosts
    debug:
      var: play_hosts
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: yes
```

This assumes, of course, that `alias` and `ansible_host` are set for all the hosts.

The hosts were:

```
AnsibleTower ansible_host=192.168.124.8 alias=fred
192.168.124.111 ansible_host=192.168.124.111 alias=barney
jaxsatB ansible_host=192.168.124.111 alias=wilma
```

The relevant output of the playbook was:

```
PLAY [Management stage] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 29 May 2020  18:09:26 -0400 (0:00:00.057)       0:00:01.332 ************ 
ok: [fred]
ok: [barney]
ok: [wilma]

TASK [New Format Hosts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 29 May 2020  18:09:30 -0400 (0:00:04.308)       0:00:05.641 ************ 
ok: [barney]
ok: [wilma]
ok: [fred]

TASK [Show ansible_host] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 29 May 2020  18:09:30 -0400 (0:00:00.450)       0:00:06.091 ************ 
ok: [fred] => {
    "ansible_host": "192.168.124.8"
}
ok: [barney] => {
    "ansible_host": "192.168.124.111"
}
ok: [wilma] => {
    "ansible_host": "192.168.124.111"
}

TASK [Show playhosts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 29 May 2020  18:09:30 -0400 (0:00:00.109)       0:00:06.200 ************ 
ok: [fred -> localhost] => {
    "play_hosts": [
        "fred", 
        "barney", 
        "wilma"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
barney                     : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
fred                       : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
wilma                      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Friday 29 May 2020  18:09:30 -0400 (0:00:00.030)       0:00:06.231 ************ 

===============================================================================
```

You do not need to set the `play_hosts` variable.  That is set by the line `hosts: new_format_hosts` in the second play.

Comment: This does not work for me if I specify a `--limit=host_group` when starting the playbook. The host_group consists of several hosts in the old format.

Comment: If you put in `--limit=host_group`, you're probably excluding `localhost`, so the part of the play that sets the new hosts does not execute at all.

Comment: if I add `localhost` to the limit I can do what I want. But I would like to avoid changes in the run command.

Comment: Well, that's what `--limit` does.  If you don't include `localhost` in the limit, the tasks for localhost won't run.

Comment: My case is pass the original limits to the imported role.
You described the case without limits.
In this way, if I put only the new play_hosts to the second playbook hosts, all the other hosts will not receive the role. And the role requires all formatted hosts in hosts and new play hosts in play_hosts

Comment: Are they two distinct, non-overlapping groups, one in the correct format and one that needs to be corrected?

Comment: Initially we have only a group which includes part of the old hosts.
In the prepare playbook, I will convert the hosts from this group (they are in play_hosts) to the new_play_hosts host group. New_play_hosts are those hosts that should be play_hosts in the next playbook.
However, I cannot put only them in hosts variable because I need to save all new format hosts in the hosts variable.

Comment: So, there is only one group, with some files in correct format and others not?

Comment: Yes, I tried to describe more clearly in paste.
https://pastebin.com/qDwL6bGE

Comment: There is no `alias`.  Where do you get that information?

Comment: Sorry, I simplified it a bit. Must be alias as I wrote in the question.

Comment: The `hosts` line of a play sets `play_hosts`.  I do not understand why you cannot set that `hosts` line and be done.

Comment: The role requires that all hosts are in the hosts variable, and the target hosts are in play_hosts where play_hosts is a subset of hosts. And all hosts are already in a new format.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  The `hosts` line in the play sets the `play_hosts` variable, which cannot be changed. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html